# SQL Server Express 'sa' login failed

Tags: sql, sql-server, qt, authentication, odbc

I've written a program in QT that connects to a SQL Server Express DB using the following code

```
    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QODBC");
    bool driverAvailable = QSqlDatabase::isDriverAvailable("QODBC");
    if( !driverAvailable )
    {
        mConnected = false;
        return false;
    }
    QString connectionTemplate = "DRIVER={SQL SERVER};SERVER=%1;DATABASE=%2;";
    QString connectionString = connectionTemplate.arg(serverIP).arg(dbName);
    db.setConnectOptions("SQL_ATTR_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT=5;SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION=SQL_OV_ODBC3;");
    db.setDatabaseName( connectionString );

    db.setUserName( username );
    db.setPassword( password );
```

However when I attempt to connect to the server I get an error stating :

```
    Login failed for user 'sa', Unable to Connect
```

1. I have checked and rechecked the password to make sure it was
   correct.
2. I have made sure that "SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode"
   is set in the server properties.
3. I have also tried to create a completely new user account and
   granted admin for the database.
4. I am able to successfully connect and run queries to the database through SQL server management studio

I am now completely stumped and I don't know what else to try, any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things to try.
Replace the IP address with the instance name.

And on that note do you have an instance
Default install would make it

MyServer\SQLExpress

Comment: Thanks! I haven't had a change to try this yet as I haven't had access to the server. Just out of curiosity, why does using the instance name make a difference from using the IP address?

Comment: database server name is stored seperately to machine name. You can get in to a right mess if you rename your server after instaling sql server.

Answer (score 0):

Just some ideas

- Note that the default server + instance name is .\SQLExpress
- You don't mention if you need to use the DB remotely. By default installation, SQLExpress is local-only and needs to be opened for remote access. Have a look [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlexpress/archive/2005/05/05/415084.aspx) for how to open it up for remote access.

Comment: Yeah sorry I forgot to mention that I'm using it locally, however I have also set it up to use IP!